# Nextjs Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, hydration

This code is displays two keyboards and allows the user to click the one they prefer.
However it gives an error: "Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML.". I believe that this has to do with how I am changing which image is rendered but I don't know how to fix it

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { Inter } from '@next/font/google'
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })
const keebs: {name: string, votes: number, id: number}[]= [{name: "Hineybeige", votes: 0, id: 0}, {name: "Vamp", votes: 0, id: 1}, {name: "Fright Club Volume 1", votes: 0, id: 2}, {name: "Tenshi", votes: 0, id: 3}, {name: "Lilac on Black", votes: 0, id: 4}, {name: "Handarbeige", votes: 0, id: 5}, {name: "Darling", votes: 0, id: 6}, {name:"Olivia++", votes: 0, id: 7}]
let keyboard1 = keebs[Math.floor(Math.random()*8)]
  let keyboard2 = keebs[Math.floor(Math.random()*8)]
  while (keyboard1.name === keyboard2.name) {
    keyboard2 = keebs[Math.floor(Math.random()*8)]
  }

export default function Home() {

  const [src1, setSrc1] = useState("/" + keyboard1.name + ".jpg")
  const [src2, setSrc2] = useState("/" + keyboard2.name + ".jpg")

  const handleSubmit = (id: number) => {
    if (id === 1) {
      keebs[keyboard1.id].votes += 1
    } 
    else if (id === 2) {
      keebs[keyboard2.id].votes += 1
    }

    keyboard1 = keebs[Math.floor(Math.random()*8)]
    keyboard2 = keebs[Math.floor(Math.random()*8)]
    while (keyboard1.name === keyboard2.name) {
      keyboard2 = keebs[Math.floor(Math.random()*8)]
    }
  
    setSrc1("/" + keyboard1.name + ".jpg")
    setSrc2("/" + keyboard2.name + ".jpg")
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Keycap Vote</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next ap" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center bg-gradient-to-b from-[#2e026d] to-[#15162c]">
        <div className="container flex flex-col items-center gap-12 px-4 py-16 ">
          <h1 className="text-5xl font-extrabold tracking-tight text-white sm:text-[5rem]">
            Keycap <span className="text-[hsl(280,100%,70%)]">Vote</span> App
          </h1>
        </div>
        <Link href="/api/auth/login">Login</Link>

        <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4 sm:grid-cols-2 md:gap-8">
        <h1 className="text-2xl font-extrabold tracking-tight text-white sm:text-[3rem] container flex flex-col items-center">{keyboard1.name}</h1>
        <h1 className="text-2xl font-extrabold tracking-tight text-white sm:text-[3rem] container flex flex-col items-center">{keyboard2.name}</h1>

          <button onClick={() => handleSubmit(1)} className="flex max-w-md flex-col gap-4 rounded-xl bg-white/10 p-4 text-white hover:bg-white/20">
            <div className="relative aspect-video h-64 max-w-[18rem]"><Image src={"/" + keyboard1.name + ".jpg"} alt="Keyboard1" layout="fill" className="rounded-xl" /></div>
          </button>

          <button onClick={() => handleSubmit(2)} className="flex max-w-md flex-col gap-4 rounded-xl bg-white/10 p-4 text-white hover:bg-white/20">
            <div className="relative aspect-video h-64 max-w-[18rem]"><Image src={"/" + keyboard2.name + ".jpg"} alt="Keyboard2" layout="fill" className="rounded-xl" /></div>
          </button>

          <h1 className="text-5xl font-extrabold tracking-tight text-white sm:text-[3rem] container flex flex-col items-center">{keyboard1.votes}</h1>
          <h1 className="text-5xl font-extrabold tracking-tight text-white sm:text-[3rem] container flex flex-col items-center">{keyboard2.votes}</h1>
        </div>

      </main>
    </>
  )
};
```

I also don't know what the usestate src1 and src2 are doing, but if I remove them it doesn't work